# emacs lisp will not start

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp, slime

I am trying to setup the [slime](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) mode in emacs for using common lisp. When I attemp to start slime with `M-x slime` I get an error message saying:

`process inferior-lisp not running`.

So, I checked the value of the variable `inferior-lisp-program` which turned out to be `"/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl"`. sbcl is an acronym for an implementation of common lisp known as steel bank common lisp. Note that this variable is defined in file `slime.el`. As I do not have sbcl (the previous directory does not even exist on my machine) installed on my machine (which runs os x 10.8.3) this will not work.

I have the clisp implementation which is located in the directory: `/opt/local/bin/`.  I tried to change the value of the variable `inferior-lisp-program` by:

`(setq inferior-lisp-program '/opt/local/bin/clisp/)`

However, this did not work and I do not know what else to try.

1. How can I get inferior-lisp to run and hence get slime to work?

**EDIT:** Here is some extra information I believe that could be helpful. If I try to just start common lisp in emacs by executing `M-x run-lisp` I get the following output from emacs:

```
(progn (load "/Users/s2s2/.emacs.d/slime/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall \
(read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-s\
erver") "/var/folders/wf/yjgymt8j14v2tqwjnny68wq00000gn/T/slime.28222"))          

Can't exec program: /opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl                                            

Process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 1                               
Can't exec program: /opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl                                            

Process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 1
```

Hope this helps! All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't use SLIME myself, so I'm sure someone else will have a better answer, but I would suggest using `M-x apropos-value RET /opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl RET` to try to find out where that value came from originally (and hence which variable needs configuring).

Comment: In fact you can probably give it the quoted value `"/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl"` for a more precise match, should there be a lot of hits for the unquoted version.

Comment: @phils could you explain how to "give it the quoted value"? I am not entirely familiar with emacs yet. I have grasped a lot of basics necessary to become more efficient though :)

Comment: I suspect the following will not work: `(setq inferior-lisp-program '/opt/local/bin/clisp/)` because you are setting the variable to a *symbol* when it should be a string. Try `(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/local/bin/clisp/")`, or do `M-x customize-variable RET inferior-lisp-program RET`.

Comment: Oops, yes, good catch.

Comment: CodeKingPlusPlus: In that instance I literally meant including the surrounding double-quotes in the pattern (as shown in the comment), as it appears that the quotes can be matched against. By the looks of huaiyuan's answer, it should have turned up `slime-lisp-implementations` as a variable matching that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `slime-lisp-implementations` has higher priority than `inferior-lisp-program` for slime if set; try this instead (adjust parameters accordingly):

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((clisp ("/opt/local/bin/clisp" "-q -I"))
        (sbcl  ("/usr/local/bin/sbcl") :coding-system utf-8-unix)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to try is to run the command in a regular shell window - just type or copy and paste the executable path there and see what `bash` tells you:

```
$ sbcl < /dev/null
bash: sbcl: command not found
$ clisp < /dev/null
<<clisp splash screen>>
$ which clisp
/usr/bin/clisp
```

Once you find out what the correct executable is, you set `inferior-lisp` to it:

```
(setq inferior-lisp "/usr/bin/clisp")
```

Notes:

1. It should be a **string**, not a **symbol**, so you need the quotes `"`.
2. It should point to a **file**, not a **directory**, so your trailing slash `/` is wrong